# org-mode fontification error

Tags: org-mode, faces, fonts, font-lock

Since some time ago I've been having this message: `org-mode fontification error` whenever I initialize `org-mode` by opening an `org` buffer. The initialization process will just get stuck and I have to press `C-g` to get out of it. Strangely all seems to be working normally once I'm in `org-mode`. All the source code blocks are fontified correctly with syntax highlighting, so I'm not sure what is the error referring to.

There was [a problem](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/fix-org-fontification-error) on this SE but the solution seems to not have solved the issue. Both the pre-installed `org` and the newest `org` induced the same error.

Comment: `org-mode` is a rapidly evolving piece of machinery.  Have you tried the latest stable version?

Comment: Unclear - not enough info. Please try to provide a step-by-step recipe, starting with `emacs -Q`. Specify your Emacs version, Org version, platform, etc.

Comment: Same here with emacs 25.1.50.1.